# Number of legends per page on pagination in Highcharts

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

Hi I am using Highcharts. In one of the chart I have too many legends so there is an overflow. In this scenario Highcharts is rightly adding pagination arrow as shown in attached pic. My question is how can I control number of legends per page. I need only 4 legends per page when pagination occurs. I could not find anything in highcharts doc. Please help. [[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no API option to set the number of series showing at the `legend.navigation` but you can control it using legend properties, such as `itemWidth`, `maxHeight` and other options for styling legend. You can also use `responsive.rules` for more precise settings.

Example config:

```
  legend: {
    align: 'center',
    itemMarginTop: 1,
    useHTML: true
  },

  responsive: {
    rules: [{
        condition: {
          maxWidth: 500,
        },
        chartOptions: {
          legend: {
            width: 250,
            itemWidth: 125,
            maxHeight: 60
          },
        }
      }
    ]
  },
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/j6gn1uto/

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/legend
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/responsive.rules